# How to modify element.text and write on xml file using iterparse lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I want to modify a text of an element on a  Huge Xml file (more than 1GB) and overwrite it, im using lxml
and the iterparse method for achieving it. But it seems that there is not a write method with iterparse, so there is a way to write my modification after my iterparse method ?

there is my code : import io

```
import os.path
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import Element

FILE =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "\MyXmlSample2Bis - Copie.xml"


context = etree.iterparse(FILE, events=("start", ))


for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02}CtrlSum':
        print(elem.text)
        elem.text = "15"
    elem.clear()  

print(etree.tostring(context.root))
```

i want to overwrite my file with the output of `etree.tostring(context.root)`

Thank you for your help

Comment: So what is the task, identify any elements named `CtrlSum` in the namespace `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02` and change them to have the content `15` while copying anything else through?

Comment: Does it have to be `lxml.etree.iterparse`? For simple tasks using SAX with an XmlFilter making that change for the desired element might make it easier to avoid building a tree.